# Don't fire onclick for touches - Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, touch

I'm writing an HTML5 app based on canvas with mouse and touch support. For mouse event I'm using this function:

```
canvas.onmousedown = function (e) { .... }
```

And this for touch events:

```
canvas.ontouchstart = function (e) { .... }
```

Click events are working fine, but when on touch input both events are fired.

Is there a way to prevent firing the click event on touch input?

Comment: try  `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` in `.ontouchstart`

Comment: generally `e.stopPropagation()`  is not recommended approach so you can try below answered approach also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try registering `onmousedown` event only when `touchstart` event is not available.

```
if(!canvas.ontouchstart){
  canvas.onmousedown = function (e) { .... }
}
```